# Thread safety read InterlockedIncremented value

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety

In my application several threads increment some counter and only one reads this value (main thread). As far I know, reading 32-bit value is thread-safe if it is aligned by double word, so I use such code:

```
{$A8}
TMyStat = class
private
  FCounter: Integer;
public
  procedure IncCounter;
  property Counter: Integer read FCounter;
...

procedure TMyStat.IncCounter;
begin
  InterlockedIncrement(FCounter);
end;
```

But I'm not sure that it's safe to mix `Interlocked` functions and direct access to value.

Should I use `InterlockedCompareExchange` instead?

```
function TMyStat.GetCounter: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedCompareExchange(FCounter, 0, 0);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a normal read. As `FCounter` is 4-aligned, reading and writing is guaranteed to be atomic.

[This holds for Intel platforms, though. I really don't know how ARM behaves. I would guess that the behaviour is the same (reading of aligned value is atomic).]

Actually, if you only increment a counter and read it, you don't even need `InterlockedIncrement`. When you read the value you'll always get either the pre-increment or post-increment value. There's no way you get a mix of both.

Comment: I have many writers and only one reader, so two (or more) threads can properly increment value only with `Interlocked` function. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you need interlocked operations when you have more than one writer

Answer (score 2):

Reading an aligned 32-bit value is *atomic* (i.e. all 32 bits are guaranteed to be consistent). But the read is not *synchronized*. You may not read the "current" value; but instead a value from the caches.

For example:

```
FCounter := 1; //number of threads running
FResult  := 0; //the answer to everything
```

And then your thread:

```
procedure ThreadProc;
begin
   FResult := 42; //set the answer before we indicate we're done
   InterlockedDecrement(FCounter);
end;
```

And then your code checks that the thread is done:

```
if (FCounter <= 0) then
begin
   //Thread is done; read the answer
   ShowMessage('The answer is: '+IntToStr(FResult));
   Exit;
end;
```

> The answer is: 0

Even though your flag said the thread set the result, you read the result value out of your local cache.

- Even though the read of `FCounter` and `FResult` is *atomic*
- they aren't *synchronized*

If you are *only* using `FCounter` then you are fine. But as soon as you use anything else and expect them to be consistent, then you need to also use something to enforce *synchronization*.

---

The strict answer to your question is that reading a 32-bit aligned value *is* already an atomic operation.

But it's entirely possible that people coming here to read this question might forget that the read being atomic is a small part of your worries.